# JBoss AS 7 not using WEB-INF hibernate lib and throwing "Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoaderService]"

Tags: spring, hibernate, migration, jboss7.x, weblogic12c

I'm migrating a Spring+Hibernate application from Weblogic 12c to JBoss AS 7, and I'm getting the following error:

```
20:07:47,395 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."connecta-presenter-2.2.1.war#ConnectaPresenterPU": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."connecta-presenter-2.2.1.war#ConnectaPresenterPU": Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1767) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_95]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_95]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_95]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: ConnectaPresenterPU] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:914)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:889)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:73)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:162)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.start(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:85)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoaderService]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.search.hcore.impl.HibernateSearchIntegrator.integrate(HibernateSearchIntegrator.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:294)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1737)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:904)
    ... 9 more
```

The `Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoaderService]` message thrown by line 126 of `org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl` is an exception **thrown only in version 4.0.1 of Hibernate Core**, which is the version that is in my JBoss AS 7 modules folder.

The thing is that my application uses **Hibernate 4.3.10**, and this specific line doesn't exist more in this version (I could see comparing the source code on Github).

The following documentation on JBoss AS 7 site states that when you migrate from Weblogic to JBoss:

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS72/How+do+I+migrate+my+application+from+WebLogic+to+AS+7#HowdoImigratemyapplicationfromWebLogictoAS7-Migrateweblogic.xmlDescriptorFileConfigurations

So there's no such code as the following in `jboss-web.xml` file:

```
<prefer-application-packages>
  <package-name>javassist.*</package-name>
</prefer-application-packages>
```

It says that JBoss always uses `WEB-INF/classes` and `WEB-INF/lib` before the internal modules.

Any idea of what's happening?

Comment: Did my answer help you @Diego?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use your own specific version of Hibernate (or any other service/software for that matter), you can do that instead of depending on JBoss AS 7 modules.

Create a new folder structure, say org/myhibernate/main in your $JBOSS_HOME\modules\system\layers\base\ directory. Put the needed jar (say my.jar) in the main folder and create a module.xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.myhibernate">
 <resources>
<!-- Modules -->
<resource-root path="my.jar" />
</resources>
<dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="sun.jdk"/>          
</dependencies>
</module>
```

Now create a jboss-deployment-structure.xml in your EAR/web folder in your workspace and include this dependency -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <sub-deployment name="yourfile.war">
        <dependencies>          
            <module name="org.myhibernate" />                       
        </dependencies>
    </sub-deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```